# Why do developers need to keep up to date with technologies and methodologies?

Tags: skills

I am always given the advice that developers need to stay up to date with the latest in technology - things like webrtc, updates on html5 and css3 and new js libraries, software methodologies like TDD, DDD, and BDD.

The question is *why*? Why do we need to constantly update ourselves? Can't we just stick with what we know and become better with it?

Comment: In software development, there's a push to do both: get to know some technologies in depth and keep up on the ever changing new technologies. This is partially why it's so damn hard to find good developers.

Comment: To address the close votes so far, I think it is a fair question, and I cannot find an exact duplicate on the site.  Just please try to keep an eye on poor answers so that we can clean them up.

Comment: I fail to see why programmers as a class must "stay up to date" with the latest in "web technology" for whatever both of those concepts actually mean in practice. A curious mind and continual learning are certainly critical for personal growth in any profession, but the false dilemma assuming "web tech" is the sole axis for personal growth makes this a bit too loaded of a question for my tastes. Looking critically at the high voted answers - do any of them even answer the question other than offering platitudes of encouragement and motivational slogans to "stay in the game"?

Comment: **Please keep comments relevant to the question or answers**.  I turn my back for 5 seconds and a discussion about cars and bicycles breaks out :)

Comment: @maple_shaft: Are we really still entertaining these "discussiony" questions on P.SE anyway?  This one seems to merely ask "Why should I learn anything new?"

Comment: @bmike: I agree with you: of course a curious mind will want to learn new stuff all the time. In this case, new stuff means something you do not know, which might be an interesting programming language that's been around for 40 years or longer (e.g. Lisp). The industry pushes us to update and to consider the latest stuff interesting, more effective by default. My main point: learning a technology you do not need just because it is new is a waste of time.

Comment: @RobertHarvey It is not as if the question is asking "How?" or "What?" as that would be NC.  It is asking **WHY** and I personally feel that is relevant and answerable.

Comment: @Ieyasu: you *can* just focus on one thing, but if you care about being gainfully employed, then you're playing the market.  It's all about supply and demand, and if there's a continued demand for the one thing you pick, great.  But probably you'll need complementary skills (usually knowledge of more than one technology is necessary in any one job) to stay employable, and it's good to have alternate skills (a different language or web framework or whatever) in case the market for your specialty starts to dry up.  Since recruiters measure skills in years it's better to start sooner!

Comment: P.S. That's really an answer, but since I don't see a button for answering, I assume I lack the necessary karma...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

New technologies surface for a reason. Usually that reason is because they are more efficient or powerful at accomplishing a particular task.

There is still value to be had in sticking with old technology for the sake of legacy systems, but when they eventually reach their end of life you'll be behind the game.

Business reasons aside, constantly learning new technologies keeps you on your toes and will open your eyes to different ways of approaching tasks, even in old technologies and so on, so forth.

Comment: +1: learning new technologies is *often* helpful, even if you never *directly* apply that technology: new views and perspectives that it provided can certainly be applied using "old" technology.

Comment: On the other hand, jumping at every new technology can also be counter-productive, because many of them disappear as fast as they surface.

Comment: @GordonBell - True... I can't speak for anyone else, but I don't usually test the waters with new technologies until they at least show signs or potential of becoming more 'mainstream' - which brings the benefits of plenty of documentation to help education and a userbase etc.

Comment: They often arise to meet needs in academia, but not in the real world. You gotta write your thesis about *something*.

Comment: @dbracey: Right, and twenty years later some big company can find this thesis that meanwhile researchers have developed into some mature technology and start selling it as _new technology_.

Comment: @Anonymous - how do you find out what technology is becoming more "mainstream"? Are there certain tech blogs that you follow?

Answer (score 27):

Although it is certainly possible to build a career on a single technology stack if you get lucky<sup>1</sup>, it is a near certainty that the technology is going to change more than once during the time when you are gainfully employed. You can (and you should) get better at what you already know, but learning new things ahead of time will help you cut down on the learning curve when the next technology shift comes to your corner of the industry.

There is a less apparent side to it, too: learning new things very often help you see the things that you already know from a different perspective, in the same way that learning a new language helps you learn more things about your current language<sup>2</sup>.

Finally, a pure entertainment value of learning new things should not be underestimated: to me, it beats watching TV hands down.

---

<sup>1</sup>For example, by picking COBOL over PL/I at the start of your career in 1965.

<sup>2</sup>This works for natural and programming languages alike.

Comment: +1 @dasblinkenlight I love this statement: "...learning new things ahead of time will help you cut down on the learning curve when the next technology shift comes to your corner of the industry." This is why I am learning [Opa](http://opalang.org/) now

Comment: it's not really entertainment, it's an ego-raising activity. It is enjoyable to have our ego risen. Learning new things, solving problems, beating someone - all that raises ego. And some people get lost in this never-ending cycle without realizing that ,and become perfect slaves for those who is actually "bulding / controlling" the world (people with power). This happens very insidiously and at some point these people start thinking that that's the way the life should be lived. How mistaken they are... :)

Answer (score 12):

> Can't we just stick with what we know and become better with it?

You *can*, but it's really easy to fall into the trap of never wanting to learn anything new. Your job prospects dwindle, your teammates stop wanting to work with you because you're "that programmer who's completely out of touch".

Mostly, you need to keep a balance. Trying to learn everything new all the time is going to lead you to be poor at many things, perceived as a flighty tinkerer. Learn a few things well, and focus at least on knowing what exists, even if you can't use it effectively.

Comment: Nothing infuriates me more at work, than having to be stuck on a team with a programmer who writes code like he did 10 years ago.  The frameworks have evolved.  The tools have evolved.  Don't you want to make your job easier?  You don't see carpenters using hand crank drills and handsaws all day when they have power tools now.  They evolved.  And like every profession new tools are invented to solve needs.  Not using the new tool, and trying to hack something together the old way is usually detrimental to the quality of what is being built.  Be it in code or in wood.

Comment: "The frameworks have evolved. The tools have evolved. Don't you want to make your job easier?": There are infinite ways of solving certain problems and sometimes a new tool or language is not better but just equivalent to the old one. But you have much more experience with the old one so you can be more productive with it. We assume too often that NEW == BETTER. Instead, we should always challenge this statement.

Comment: @Giorgio - It's one thing to have healthy skepticism of 'the next big thing'. It's another to put your head into the sand as real progress passes you by. The later is way too common.

Comment: @Telastyn: I would assign 50 % to both attitudes: sometimes I have the impression that a new technology is pushed just because it is new. And it is only an alternative (not a better) way of doing things. So we have to spend months becoming proficient with the new technology and after that we are again as productive as we used to be with the old one. But of course, you are right that putting your head into the sand is also wrong and one should always watch out for new things.

Comment: @Giorgio, how do you know if the new way is better or not if you don't learn about or try it?

Comment: @Chad: It is a trade-off: we evaluate costs / benefits and then decide if we want to try. E.g. I know Java quite well and I have never wanted to learn C# (beyond very simple examples) because I do not see any clear advantage considering the time I would have to spend on it. On the other hand I am learning Scala even though it will take me some time before I can be as proficient as with Java. Probably a C# developer would want to try F# and never consider Java for similar reasons. So, sometimes a rough idea is enough to discard something that doesn't seem to offer a clear advantage.

Comment: @Giorgio, you are still learning. Nobody is saying you have to learn language x, or framework y. But, you should learn something new all the time. You can't know it all. I learn new things all the time, you can even learn more in your stack, but exposing yourself to some different languages is a good thing.  Going from C# to Java, won't teach you much.  They're too similar. However, learning a functional language. Or TDD is about the paradigm, not a specific technology. And if you are invested in a technology, you should keep up to date. That means .Net Framework 4.0 if you're into .Net.

Comment: "That means .Net Framework 4.0 if you're into .Net.": That's exactly the point. If I am a C# developer, like I do not feel the need to learn Java (it is a bit different, but not different enough that I gain something from it), I might not get any real advantage from upgrading to the latest .Net version. Yet, I am forced to upgrade. It is a marketing thing: sometimes the industry innovates just because they have to in order to keep selling their products (compilers, tools, etc) and developers have to buy them. I think the OP has a point here.

Comment: No, you should upgrade. I'm looking at .Net code right now. It's in "Framework 3.5" however, the code makes almost no use of the features after Framework 1.1. An app that should be under 100,000 lines, is at nearly a million because it's not taking advantage of the language advancements. Now, you might argue...but it works now. And yes, it does. But when 80% of your budget on an applicatoin is spent in maintenance, wouldn't you want to maintain less code?  Less code means less bugs. Less bugs means less maintenance. Less maintenance means we can work on new projects to provide value.

Comment: @Chad: You still don't get my point. Of course you should upgrade to 4.0 if it is better. But if you found out that it is not better (as far as your needs are concerned) you'd probably be forced to upgrade anyway.

Answer (score 7):

Well it's probably due to the fact that you're a web developer and the technologies in that field are very volatile with languages, platforms, tools, and methodologies rising and falling in popularity. It's a field that is very VERY high level. If any of the layers beneath it are altered, that changes the position on top. And, frankly, it's new (ish). New fields have a lot of room for innovation.

Personally, I work on embedded devices, learned C, and that's worked pretty well for me.

But I'm still learning new things on a fairly regular basis. Sockets, SQL libraries, ncurses, objects in C. And methodologies are loosely coupled with technologies. Unit testing was taught horribly at my school, and I'm just now wrapping my head around it. I just heard about dependency injection the other day, and realized that's exactly how I solved my last problem with unit testing a console function.

Most programmers aren't factory workers that do the same thing every day. Those jobs can (and should) be automated away. Nobody pays for yet another bubble-sort implementation. It's been done.

Comment: +1: Good answer. One should learn the technologies that one needs or finds useful. New technologies are important and one should look around to know what is going on. But NEW should not be the only criterion to choose what we learn. Also, if C suits your programming need, I agree that it can be a good language to work with, even if it has been around for a long time.

Comment: This also points out that new technologies are often more layers on top of existing older technologies.  What's your VM implemented in? C or C++.

Comment: Dependency injection is just a new name for a very old idea.

Answer (score 6):

I'd say you *can* ignore a lot of what's out there.  Much of it is hype and fad and new names for old technology.  The real advances will soon be replaced by even newer ones that don't *really* depend on the old ones, even though the old timers say you ought to understand the old ones to understand the new.  If you left the field for 10 years, when you came back you'd only be 2 years behind.

That said, spotting the *real* new technogy can be tricky.  I'm glad I didn't miss OOP, but it sure looked like just a handful of buzz words at first.  And you often need to use current technology to do a job, even if everyone will have forgotten it in 3 years.

The software technology hype and confusion multiplies the change we have to deal with day-to-day.  But electronic technology actually *is* advancing rapidly, and pushing software along with it.  There's a lot of *real* change out there.  We're still driving the cars, flying the planes, and going into space with the same vehicles we used in 1965.  But the electronic hardware from 1995 is hopelessly obsolete.

So the deep answer to your question is that the scientists and engineers working with electricity have been very busy.  The software needs to evolve to take advantage of the hardware.  Worse (or rather--better?), I think the software's been left way behind by the hardware.  If the hardware people all retired tomorrow, software would evolve furiously for the next two decades at least.

If you need the new technology to do a job, you need to learn it.  If there's a chance it's a new technology that will still be here 20 years from now, you need to keep an eye on it--and if you watch 20 techs that die for every one that lives, you're doing pretty good.  And you actually can ignore everything else.  Except for that one bit of obvious smoke that will underlie all the software of the 2020's.

Comment: +1: I agree with you regarding hype. A lot innovation is (unfortunately) hype and we should choose the new technologies we spend time on very carefully. One of the hypes of the moment is lambdas (which, BTW, I consider a very useful concept): every **modern** language must have them (C#, C++, Java?) otherwise it is not cool any more! But lambdas have been around for 50 years and no one cared when these languages were initially designed. Now they are being added as an afterthought just to follow the latest hype. ;-)

Comment: @Giorgio: I hope not Java. Lambdas are a good example (though simpler and so less troublesome than some). I use them in C#, and I love them, but the only person who'll ever regret not knowing what they are is the person who's just been told to fix code that's full of them.

Comment: What do you mean by "I hope not Java"? That they will not be introduced? I like and use lambdas (in Scheme, Haskell): they are a pretty easy concept. But in C#, C++ and Java they seem to me a late addition that somehow does not fit with the rest of the language. I doubt that the inventors did not know any Lisp but they decided that lambdas did not belong in these languages. Now they have become a must. So, I like lambdas a lot, but in C#, C++ and Java they seem just a hype that is used to sell new compilers, books, and so on.

Comment: @Giorgio: Java is (or was) rather a minimalist language.  You don't need to know a lot (lambdas, for instance) to understand what someone else has written.  I like that.  C# is a maximalist language.  Every new line can introduce tech you've never seen before.  It's a blast to write, less so to read.  Neither needs lambda's, though they do help more in C# than they would in Java for syntax reasons.  But they're cool and they save a couple lines of code.  In other words, you're right.  But that's C#, _not_ Java.  Yet.

Comment: "No one needs lambdas"... until they *do* need them.  They are left out because they seem obscure at first, but when you're backed into the right corner, they can get you out.

Comment: @Brandon: Did you read my comment? I find lambdas a very easy and useful concept. They are fine in Scheme (they are one of the few concepts of the language), but in Java I think they are in contrast with its (original) minimalistic design: Besides lambdas there are hundred of constructs that are useful and that could be added to any language, but then you end up with a bazaar-language. Going back to the point: my impression is that Java-lambdas are just a way to force developers to switch to Java 8 when it will come out, without really improving the language as a whole.

Comment: @Giorgio: I wasn't directing that comment particularly at you, and I didn't mean to give the impression that I was arguing with you.  I agree that lambdas seem odd in Java.  (But I don't necessarily agree with Java's original design decision, though. I find that most attempts to make everything easy for beginners end up being a mess that is harder in the end, because all the missing pieces get bolted on later.  I prefer removing accidental complexity, and leave in all the complexity that has proven useful.  Of course people disagree often about which category something fits in :)  )

Comment: @Brandon: Excuse me, I probably interpreted your comment in the wrong way. Regarding complexity: I tend to be a minimalist regarding language design. I think most of the power of a language comes from its ecosystem (tool support, libraries, community), see e.g. Java, Python, Ruby. For example, even without lambdas, Java has a library for almost every task I can think of. This makes a difference to me as a programmer much more than some additional language construct. So I am more in favour of a small, stable language with a big and growing collection of libraries.

Comment: @Brandon: I don't think Java's for beginners.  It's more for people who have to maintain large, complex, intricate systems and who do not have time to keep up with a vast and rapidly evolving language.  Of course, this does have the effect of constraining beginners and others who like lots of tools available and want to use as many of them as they can.

Comment: @RalphChapin: I wasn't saying that Java *is* for beginners, just that some of its early design decisions were based on making things easier (for beginners, basically).  What the language is now is a totally different matter, which is part of my point.  Sometimes those decisions bite you.  But there are examples were this is far more pronounced than Java. I didn't have only Java in mind when I made the comment about how these things have a negative long-term effect.

Comment: @iconoclast: With 20 years of experience as a programmer I do not consider myself a beginner. Yet, the fact that Java is (was) a relatively simple and clean language makes me more productive (I can develop more complex software with less effort). I think it is a misconception that a simple language is for beginners: a simple language will allow **any programmer** with any degree of experience to focus more on certain aspects of development (e.g. managing a complex architecture, refactoring) because they spend less time dealing with other aspects (e.g. memory management, cryptic syntax, etc).

Answer (score 3):

IMHO, you need to find a balance. That takes skill and experience.

You need to find one or two languages you specialize in, keep up to date in framework/style changes that evolve in this language, and keep your skills top-notch.

But you also have to see how this language evolves, and understand the dynamics of software development as a whole. Will Java be around in 10 years, is Phyton there to stay, is PHP going to be replaced with .NET and Mono?

These are large scale, strategic questions, answers to which will let you become highly valued professional in your field, while having some solid backup (1 or 2 languages) and knowing when to move on from your main platform.

IMHO, following all the modern languages that are being developed every day is one of the biggest problems for the whole industry. We have ton of undeveloped, dead-end languages with almost no professionals in them, and people who waste time on them are rarely real professionals in even 1 language. Mostly they write code that's mix of all languages and does nothing right. At the same time, amount of man-years that's wasted on these nonstandard languages could be spent on improving few core language frameworks and specs.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, many new technologies emerge to address new needs and therefore they make it easier to solve certain problems. Therefore you should keep up to date and at least know what is going in your field and understand which new technologies are relevant for you.

On the other hand, I think that sometimes there is also a hype factor in certain innovations: Some ideas are extremely old but only in recent years they are being pushed to become mainstream. Sometimes I have the impression that a new programming language (or a new version thereof) is pushed just because "new is better" and a new technology means new books, new programming tools, new compilers, new programming courses, or in other words, revenue.

So it can happen that you have to learn a new technology without seeing any real advantage wrt the technology you had been using before, otherwise you risk to be out of the market because your skills look *old fashioned*.
It is up to you to follow the development of new technologies and try to understand which ones can make you more productive, and which ones are just convenient to make your CV look better.

Bottom line: I think you should try to learn what you really find useful, regardless of whether it is new or old.

Answer (score 2):

Because "sticking with what you know" represents a failure to "get better at it." You don't have to adopt every new practice and framework that comes along but you should at least have an informed opinion on the popular ones. In web development just asking the question would look horrible to an interviewer. Web dev is littered with the career-corpses of people who wanted to stop learning new stuff after 2000 and that's as it should be because they make more work for the rest of us. Stay away from dev if it doesn't interest you. It's a lousy $/hour ratio if the part where you learn new stuff feels like work.

Comment: Because "sticking with what you know" represents a failure to "get better at it.": One way to read this is that by sticking with the same technology for a longer time you get a deeper knowledge of it, whereas jumping from one technology to the next every two or three years will only allow you to have superficial knowledge, i.e. you will never be really familiar with any of them.

Comment: I would not understand JavaScript as well as I do if I hadn't branched out a bit and understood it from a perspective of how other languages actually work or kept an eye out on current notions of best practice and explored what people are actually doing under the hood of their frameworks and libraries. I don't think it's really possible to improve as a developer at a career-reasonable rate without regular exposure to new ideas.

Comment: Reppen: I totally agree with you on this.